# Which php function or a combination of functions can I use to update an array to gain the disired output below?

Tags: php, arrays

Current Array Output:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 165       <-- first occurrence 
        [score] => 3.813   <-- first value
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 167
        [score] => 3.772
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 165  <-- second
        [score] => 4.421 <-- second value
    )
```

Desired Updated Array's Output after some php function:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 165     <-- update this key 
        [score] => 8.234  <-- with $ary[0][score] + $ary[2][score]
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 167
        [score] => 3.772
    )
```

Since the id key was updated we don't need the `$ary[2][id]` and `$ary[2][score]`, so remove it.

Is there a magical function? or Should we write a special function to make this happen?
Thanks!

Comment: You probably need to write a special function.

Comment: You can use `unset($ary[2])` to remove it.

Comment: is this supposed to be general purpose (i.e. tot up _all_ elements that have the same id), or for this specific three element array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a general purpose function which tots up all of the records that share the same `id` value:

(NB: probably not idiomatic PHP, but it does work)

```
function totup($a) {

    // create temporary array keyed on ID, containining sum of scores
    $tmp = array();
    foreach ($a as $row) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $score = $row['score'];
        $tmp[$id] += $score;
    }

    // then convert that array back to (id, score) tuples
    $res = array();
    foreach ($tmp as $id => $score) {
        $res[] = array(id => $id, score => $score);
    }
    return $res;
}
```

Test run:

```
$tmp = array(
    array(id => 165, score => 3.813),
    array(id => 167, score => 3.772),
    array(id => 165, score => 4.421));

$foo = totup($tmp);
print_r($foo);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 165
            [score] => 8.234
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 167
            [score] => 3.772
        )

)
```

Comment: Awesome, after I changed $array[] to $res[] within the totup(), it worked exactly as you intended. Other than the little typeO, your function totup did the trick!  Thanks Alnitak!

Comment: oops, yes, little copy&paste error - I fixed the version I was testing but forgot to correct the posting.

Answer (score 0):

`$ary[0][score] += $ary[2][score];

unset(yourArray[2]);`